# Wordpress: Put name and email into input type

Tags: wordpress

I use Contact Form 7 and i need to this point:-

when user login to my site and need to contact me from site, I put page for this. But i Need when user open this page, Put his name and email into input type

How can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://contactform7.com/setting-default-values-to-the-logged-in-user/) for the list of available fields for logged in users

```
Your Name: [text* your-name default:user_display_name]

Your E-mail: [email* your-email default:user_email]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass **user_display_name** and **user_email** as default

```
[text* your-name default:user_display_name]
[email* your-email default:user_email]
```